# Would the rock formations in the giant's causeway scale?

Tags: science-based, geology

In my world there is a kingdom built on hexagonal pillars like you see at the giant's causeway. Your social status is based on how tall the pillar you live on is. Sort of like the image below.

[image]

The pillars would be 30-50 meters across, would it be possible for a rock formation like this to form at that size?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: According to [this](http://www.iflscience.com/environment/why-columnar-basalt-almost-always-hexagonal/) you need one column to form and then the rest around it will form with similar size. Sadly, I don't know how to get that first one to be this big, or if it's even possible.

Comment: In the real world it is actually the height of the pillar which is determined by the social status. Basically, rich and powerful people buy or build homes on the heights; a poor powerless family having a home high up will be forced to sell and move out.

Comment: This may be useful, it discusses the scale of columnar jointed volcanic rocks: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225458985_Scales_of_columnar_jointing_in_igneous_rocks_Field_measurements_and_controlling_factors

Answer (score 6):

Devils Tower
[image]
from https://media.nationalgeographic.org/assets/photos/000/265/26550.jpg

from https://pubs.usgs.gov/bul/1021i/report.pdf

> One of the most striking features of the Tower is its polygonal
>   columns (fig. 53). Most of the columns are 5 sided, but some are 4 and
>   6 sided. The larger columns measure 6 to 8 feet in diameter at their
>   base and taper gradually upward to about 4 feet at the top.

8 feet in diameter is bigger than a half meter; big enough to pitch a tent.  But not big enough for some swanky mansion.  You could however have several columns in aggregate that presented a 40 foot diameter surface.  Or one could have multiple Devil's Towerlets.

Or you could just assert that they did get as big as you want them to be, because I gather your story is not a geological treatise.  Something that is big can always be made bigger in fiction.  That is one of the chief uses of fiction.

Comment: Big fan of that last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

That rock formation is called [columnar basalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt#Columnar_basalt). As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_with_columnar_jointed_volcanics) columnar basalt can form in many different sizes. How large these columns become is dependent on how slowly the lava that formed them cools. The slower the basalt cools the larger the columns that may form. It is possible, though unlikely, that if the lava cooled **extremely** slowly it could form pillars 30-50 meters accross. On earth we haven't observed any pillars much over 2 meters wide.

Comment: At Devil's Postpile, pillars are up to 18 meters high (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_Postpile_National_Monument#Devil.27s_Postpile)

Comment: @user58697 Good thing we're talking about width. I've edited for clarity.